# VS Code doesn't recognize imported libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed matplotlib for a project and it was working fine. Today I tried to add a histogram but I am not able to because VS Code doesn't recognize the extensions anymore. Maybe the problem is with Visual Studio Code itself, in which case I don't know what to do.

The error that it gives:

```
line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

class Particelle():  
    
    def __init__(self, id=0, r=np.zeros(2), v=np.zeros(2), R=1E-2,m=1): #valori di default
        self.id, self.r, self.v, self.R, self.m= id,r,v,R,m #valori individuali

class Sis(): 
    
    x=2
    y=2
    
    def __init__(self, t=1E-1, N=1): 
        self.t, self.N= t,N
        self.particelle=[Particelle(i) for i in range(self.N)] 
        self.entropia_values = []
    
    def collision_detection(self):
        ignore_list = []
        for particella1 in self.particelle:
            if particella1 in ignore_list:
                continue
            x, y = particella1.r
            if ((x > self.x/2 - particella1.R) or (x < -self.x/2+particella1.R)):
                particella1.v[0] *= -1
            if ((y > self.y/2 - particella1.R) or (y < -self.y/2+particella1.R)):
                particella1.v[1] *= -1

            for particella2 in self.particelle:
                if id(particella1) == id(particella2):
                    continue
                m1, m2, r1, r2, v1, v2 = particella1.m, particella2.m, particella1.r, particella2.r, particella1.v, particella2.v
                if np.dot(r1-r2, r1-r2) <= (particella1.R + particella2.R)**2:
                    v1_new = v1 - 2*m1 / \
                        (m1+m2) * np.dot(v1-v2, r1-r2) / \
                        np.dot(r1-r2, r1-r2)*(r1-r2)
                    v2_new = v2 - 2*m1 / \
                        (m1+m2) * np.dot(v2-v1, r2-r1) / \
                        np.dot(r2-r1, r2-r1)*(r2-r1)
                    particella1.v = v1_new
                    particella2.v = v2_new
                    ignore_list.append(particella2)
                
                
                
    def increment(self):
        ignore_list = self.collision_detection()
        for particelle in self.particelle:
            particelle.r += self.t * particelle.v
        entropia_val = self.entropia()
        self.entropia_values.append(entropia_val)
            
    def posizione_particelle(self):
        return[particelle.r for particelle in self.particelle ]
    
    def velocità_particelle(self):
        return[np.sqrt(np.dot(particelle.v, particelle.v )) for particelle in self.particelle ]
    
    def entropia(self):
        entropia = 0
        for particella in self.particelle:
            entropia -= particella.m * np.log(np.linalg.norm(particella.v))
        return entropia

N=100
sis=Sis(N=N)

for particelle in sis.particelle:
    particelle.r = np.random.uniform(
        [-sis.x/2, -sis.y/2], [sis.x/2, sis.y/2], size=2) 
    particelle.v = 1*np.array([np.cos(np.pi/4), np.sin(np.pi/4)]) 



fig, (ax1, ax2 ) = plt.subplots(1, 2,  figsize=(10, 4))
scatter = ax1.scatter([], [])
entropia, = ax2.plot([], [])

vm=np.linspace(0,2,10)#velocità media

def update(frame):
    sis.increment()
    scatter.set_offsets(np.array(sis.posizione_particelle()))
    entropia.set_data(range(frame + 1), sis.entropia_values)
    
    
    return scatter, entropia, 


def init():
    ax1.set_xlim(-sis.x/2, sis.x/2)
    ax1.set_ylim(-sis.y/2, sis.y/2)
    ax2.set_xlim(0, 1200)
    ax2.set_ylim(0, 50)
    return scatter, entropia, 

ani=FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(1200), init_func=init, blit=True, interval=1/30, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

I tried restarting VS Code.
I tried upgrading pip.
I tried to reinstalling matplotlib.

Comment: check which python environment your VS is running. also is this VS or VS Code?

Comment: It's in VS code,  the venv is the same. the strange thing is that if i run the code on the dekstop it works, but if i open the code to change it VS Code doesn't recognize the extensions

Comment: @Ftel what do you mean "the venv is the same"? Which interpreter is VSCode using, and how do you know? This should be the first thing you verify in this situation. How *exactly* are you running the code? Please give us details. This is obviously some problem with how you've set up and how you are using the text editor

Comment: i meant that the virtual environment in which i was trying to change the code was the same in which the code was running before it broke. I solved it. it was a problem with the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

double check your python interpreter version. make sure you are using the python interpreter where the matplotlib installed. you can see on the lower-right of you visual studio IDE. you can click the version and click the recommended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Ftel had already mentioned `upgrading pip I tried to reinstall Matplotlib`, thus your answer is invalid and needs to be deleted.

Comment: @Andrew that has nothing to do with what this answer is saying, which is probably the most reasonable explanation for the OP's problem

Comment: hi @juanpa.arrivillaga, my answer is from experienced.

Comment: @EvangelineDelaCruz I'm agreeing with your answer, I'm responding to the other comment